# How to run Scala IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scala-ide

I am tring to install scala-ide(eclipse) on ubuntu.

I downloaded [scala-ide](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/4.4.1-vfinal-luna-211-20160504/scala-SDK-4.4.1-vfinal-2.11-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz) form http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html

I can see below files and folder but I could not figure out how to start eclipse. I am expecting for .sh file to start which might be missing.

[image]

Comment: Do care to comment if downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `eclipse` file. Click right button on file and choose `Run` option by left mouse click.
Make sure you have `JAVA_HOME` set and java in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not have java installed earlier so run was missing.

Comment: @amit_kumar Does this Scala IDE requires JAVA 8?

Comment: I am using Java 8, but works fine with Java 7 as well.